# Libgdx resize after resume

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing an android game application in Libgdx. I am very new at Libgdx game engine, i have a problem about rendering/resizing after resume the screen. [image: Can't resize after pause]

After resizing screen works well . But not always. Sometimes it resizes almost half of screen.
[image: Sometimes i get this error as well]

I couldn't figure out the problem. I did google it , found some solutions but they didn't help me as well.

```
 //This is my manifest in the project.
 <activity
        android:name="com.tll.game.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 //Resize function in Game class
  @Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
    camera.update();
}
//i commented the resize function in Screen class, but it didn't work
  @Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    //viewPort.update(width, height, true);
    //camera.update();
}
//EDIT: ViewPort And Camera 
protected static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 800, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 480;
protected Camera camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
protected Viewport viewPort = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.fill,VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, camera);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection)` in your render function.

For more information have a look at [these tests](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ViewportTest2.java).

Also, do not comment out the resize function in Screen.

Comment: I did add this line to render function but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

make sure you have set the viewport as your stages viewport; eg:

```
stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(800, 480));
```

in the resize method, update it like so

```
stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
```

I'd recommend using a stretch viewport in your case. Further, camera.update() belongs in the render method, or at least that's where I've got it.
For more info on view ports: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still has the same problem